# find a sentence $\alpha$ in some language L such that

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Let $K=\{k\in\mathbb N : k\mod2\not=0$ and $k\mod3\not=0\}$
find a sentence $\alpha$ in some language L such that 
$K=${$n\in\mathbb N :$exists a structure $M$ such that $M\models\alpha$ and $|W^M|=n$}

Comment: For future reference, you can use \{ and \} to write braces within a math environment. See my edit.

Comment: Also what is $W$?

Comment: W is the domain, I'm just used calling it "the world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** We are working in the predicate calculus with equality, and with an additional binary predicate symbol $R$. We build the sentence $\alpha$ as follows:

(i) Let $\beta$ be the conjunction of the usual axioms that say that $R$ is an equivalence relation (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity).

(ii) Let $\gamma$ be the sentence that says the following. There is an object $x$ such that the only object $y$ such that $R(x,y)$ is $x$, and such that any object $z$ not equal to $x$ bears the $R$ relation to precisely $6$ objects.

(iii) Let $\delta$ be the sentence that says the following. There exist $5$ objects which are distinct and congruent to each other, and such that any object $z$ not equal to one of these $5$ bears the $R$ relation to precisely $6$ objects.

If we let $\alpha$ be the sentence $\beta\land(\gamma\lor\delta)$, then $\alpha$ will have the desired property.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know how much further detail is expected. The sentences $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are in principle very easy to write down, but they do give the typing fingers quite a lot of exercise, particularly if we insert all the parentheses that are in principle required.  But the *idea* is pleasantly simple.